# Optimizing a query on large dataset - with JOIN or IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given i have articles which are tagged, one article can have n tags.
Currently there are around 250k tag-entries which all point back 
onto their belonging article.

Now i want to find all tags from articles matching certain criteria. 
I came up with two different approaches. Both which have drawbacks and are slow.
May be someone can point me in the right direction on how to speed them up or even come
up with a better solution.

**Keys (ind,rindex) are varchar(255) unfortunately this cant be changed**

### Query #1

taking 7.5  - subselect returns 60 records in 50ms

```
SELECT count(*) AS tagscount, tags.value FROM tags 
  WHERE tags.`rindex` IN 
  ( 
    SELECT article.ind 
       FROM article 
       INNER JOIN struktur ON (struktur.ind = article.struktur) 
    WHERE article.date = '2011-12-21'
  ) 
  AND tags.`rtable` = 'article'
  GROUP BY tags.value ORDER BY tagscount DESC LIMIT 20
```

### Query #2

taking 60ms

```
SELECT count(*) AS tagscount, tags.value FROM tags 
  INNER JOIN article ON (article.ind = tags.rindex AND tags.rtable = 'article')
  LEFT JOIN structure ON (article.structure = structure.ind)
WHERE article.date = '2011-12-21'
GROUP BY tags.value ORDER BY tagscount DESC LIMIT 20
```

### The Strange Part - *Important*

When i change `article.date = '2011-12-21'` into `article.date >= '2009-12-21'`
**Query #1**

- taking 10.1s - subselect returns 18k rows in 70ms

**Query #2**

- taking 14.2s

If you need further information i'll be happy to provide

## SCHEMAS

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM tags;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ind     | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| rtable  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| rindex  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| value   | varchar(40)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> SHOW indexes FROM tags
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tags  |          0 | tags_ind            |            1 | ind         | A         |      275834 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tags  |          1 | tags_tag            |            1 | tag         | A         |       27583 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| tags  |          1 | tags_rindex         |            1 | rindex      | A         |       55166 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tags  |          1 | tags_rindex_tabelle |            1 | tabelle     | A         |           4 |       30 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tags  |          1 | tags_rindex_tabelle |            2 | rindex      | A         |       55166 |       50 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM structure;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ind                    | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM artikel;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| ind                | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |            |       |
| date               | date         | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

## EXPLAIN

```
mysql> explain #1
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type   | possible_keys                                                                       | key                 | key_len | ref                 | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | tags     | ref    | tags_rindex_tabelle                                                                 | tags_rindex_tabelle | 32      | const               | 177175 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | artikel  | eq_ref | artikel_ind,zeitraum_start_i,freigabe_i,korrektur_i,struktur_i,artikel_start_slot_i | artikel_ind         | 257     | func                |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | struktur | eq_ref | struktur_ind,struktur_host                                                          | struktur_ind        | 257     | ec.artikel.struktur |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
mysql> explain #2
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys                                                                       | key                 | key_len | ref                 | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags     | ref    | tags_rindex,tags_rindex_tabelle                                                     | tags_rindex_tabelle | 32      | const               | 177175 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | artikel  | eq_ref | artikel_ind,zeitraum_start_i,freigabe_i,korrektur_i,struktur_i,artikel_start_slot_i | artikel_ind         | 257     | ec.tags.rindex      |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | struktur | eq_ref | struktur_ind,struktur_host                                                          | struktur_ind        | 257     | ec.artikel.struktur |      1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You are comparing two different result sets here, why are you doing `left outer join` in #2? It should be `inner join` based on Query#1.

Comment: thanks i updated the code - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you add the schemas for all tables used in the queries? (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`) And also the output of `EXPLAIN your_query` for the 2 queries. So we can understand better what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` on your query? In most cases this will give valuable insights on performance of query execution.

Comment: It says the query uses the defined keys as well as filesort which is to avoid

Comment: I updated the question to contain the results of `EXPLAIN` - may be you see something i missed or am not aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `artikel.ind` is not restricted to being ascending lexical order in the same order as `artikel.date`. If it is, the obvious solution would be to add a restriction to the `rindex` which corresponded to the date range.

As it is, it looks like an appropriate plan is being used.

Your best bet without changing data types would be to create a materialized view indexed on `(artikel.date, tags.value, artikel.ind)` and then query that.

Comment: Thanks i'll implement that - I am marking this as correct since its the only answer.